# Change Featured Image Size of the Post

Tags: images

When I click on a post it opens up and it is displaying the featured image at the top of the post. The featured image is being displayed as a width of 1024 x 768. This is taking up the whole screen and I want to make this image a lot smaller.

The content is being display by the `the_content()` function which I've read calls `the_post_thumbnail` but how can I set this so that Wordpress displays the Medium image instead of the full size image everytime?

Comment: Are those the original image dimensions? Can you link to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you WordPress Admin, Go to Settings > Media, here you can set the default size of 'thumbnail','medium' and 'large'.

If you read through the codex page of [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) you would have found that it has parameters that can be used to fetch a precised size of the image.

> ```
> the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'
>
> the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
> the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
> the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
> the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
>
> the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );  // Other resolutions
> ```

So, you can try `the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );`

Comment: I understand the codex but my issue is that it's being called from `the_content` function and I don't have access to it as it's being called since it's in that function.

Comment: have you tried changing the size in WordPress admin?

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't change

Comment: `the_content` do not internally call the_post_thumbnail unless there is a hook added by theme or some plugin. `the_content` only outputs the content of the post. Some possibilities are  1) featured image is embedded in post content as well (you can verify by editing the post) 2) theme template is displaying full image before `the_content()` is called, its probably happening in one of the theme file. 3) some plugin/theme function is using `the_content` filter hook to add full image before the post content.